# Get user's Time zone Time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

[image]

Above image shows the PST time according to the server which app is being hosted.So my requirement is how to show the time of the user who logs into the site according to his Time Zone ?

Comment: (Note that it's not clear whether you really need a time *zone*, or just the UTC offset for a specific point in time. You probably want to just pass the UTC point in time to the Javascript, and do the rendering on the client side which will be able to know the UTC offset for that point in time.)

Comment: @JonSkeet As shown above it's a PST time(USA & Canada).So I need to show the time according to the client's time zone and then save that time on DB ? How can I do that ?

Comment: Why would you want to store a time zone in the database? Do you *really* need to do that? As for displaying the right time - as I said, just send a UTC point in time to the client, and render it in Javascript, which knows the local time zone.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't need to store the time zone in the DB.Need to save the user's log-in time according to his time zone.

Comment: *Why* do you need to save that? What are you going to do with it later? If you really need to, you can determine it in Javascript as show in the duplicate question.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is an app which logs the employees login and logout times.That's why it requires to save that time.Is there any problem about that,if I save the UI shown time ?

Comment: Why not just log the UTC time? Aside from anything else, that means it's *trivial* to find out how long a user has been logged in for - you don't need to take daylight saving time into account, for example. At any time, you can later display that in the user's time zone - or in any other time zone. Another benefit is that then you're not trusting the user's browser for anything... what would the impact be under your scheme if they'd manually changed their time zone?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep.I got your point.Thanks a lot.If you put your comments as an answer,I can accept it.Thanks again. :)

Comment: No can do, as I've already closed the question as a duplicate. There are probably duplicates of "how should I store date/time values" too... probably best to just delete this question to be honest.